# Not able to read file content with sed command

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to read the below file line by line to perform the below operations

1. Extract the name of the file/directory alone and assign it one variable,
2. Extract the permission available in the line and add comma between the permission. Then assign it to another variable,
3. At last applying setfacl logic as shown in the output section.

`File`

```
# file:  /disk1/script_1/ user::rwx group::r-x group:service:r-x mask::r-x other::r-x
# file:  /disk1/script_1//hello.txt user::rw- group::r-- other::r--
# file:  /disk1/script_1//bkp_10.txt user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x
```

`Code`

```
input="bkp_23.txt"
while IFS= read -r line;
do
echo $line
file_name=`sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $file_name
file_perm=`sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' "$line" | awk '{$1=""}{print}' | tr ' ' ',' | awk 
'{sub(",","")}1'`
echo $file_perm
echo "setfacl -m "$file_perm" "$file_name" executing"
done <"$input"
```

`Output`

```
setfacl -m user::rwx,group::r-x,group:service:r-x,mask::r-x,other::r-x  /disk1/script_1/
setfacl -m  user::rw-,group::r--,other::r--  /disk1/script_1//hello.txt
setfacl -m  user::rwx,group::r-x,other::r-x   /disk1/script_1//bkp_10.txt
```

`Error`

```
sed: can't read # file: /disk1/script_1/ user::rwx group::r-x group:service:r-x mask::r-x other::r-x: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your input file seems nicely formatted.  Just do `while read _ _ path perm; do ...` and let read split the columns into the variables for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to echo the line content along with sed logic like this 
`file_name=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' | awk '{print $1}')`

`file_perm=$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/# file:\(.*\)/\1/g' | awk '{$1=""}{print}' | tr ' ' ',' | awk '{sub(",","")}1')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input
# file:  /disk1/script_1/ user::rwx group::r-x group:service:r-x mask::r-x     other::r-x
# file:  /disk1/script_1//hello.txt user::rw- group::r-- other::r--
# file:  /disk1/script_1//bkp_10.txt user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x
$ while read  _ _ path perms; do perms="$(echo "$perms" | tr -s ' ' ,)"; echo path="$path", perms="$perms"; done < input
path=/disk1/script_1/, perms=user::rwx,group::r-x,group:service:r-x,mask::r-x,other::r-x
path=/disk1/script_1//hello.txt, perms=user::rw-,group::r--,other::r--
path=/disk1/script_1//bkp_10.txt, perms=user::rwx,group::r-x,other::r-x
```